# Grabbing specific sections of a txt file via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell scripting, but I feel I am overlooking a simple answer, hopefully some of you can help.

My company exports files from all of our computers with a section around the middle of Mapped Network Printers. It looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mapped Network Printers:
NetworkAddress\HP425DN    [DEFAULT PRINTER]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Local Printers:
```

What I have been asked to do is copy just the Mapped Network Printers to a new text file.

I tried using Select-String with a context parameter, but I have no way of knowing how many network printers there are, so I can't guess.

I also tried using the following code which I found on this site, but it returns nothing:

```
$MapPrint  = gc C:\Users\User1\Documents\Config.txt

$from =  ($MapPrint | Select-String -pattern "Mapped Network Printers:" | 
Select-Object LineNumber).LineNumber
$to =  ($MapPrint  | Select-String -pattern "-------------------------------
--------------------------------------------" | Select-Object 
LineNumber).LineNumber

$i = 0
$array = @()
foreach ($line in $MapPrint)
{
foreach-object { $i++ }
    if (($i -gt $from) -and ($i -lt $to))
    {
    $array += $line      
    }
}
$array
```

I basically want to start the search at "Mapped Network Printers" and end it at the next row of "------"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-String` has no feature for extracting a *range* of lines based on *content*.

The simplest approach is to read the file *as a whole* and use the `-replace` operator to extract the range via a regular expression (regex):

```
$file = 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Config.txt'
$regex = '(?sm).*^Mapped Network Printers:\r?\n(.*?)\r?\n---------------------.*'
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace $regex, '$1'
```

Reading an input file as a whole can be problematic with files too large to fit into memory, but that's probably not a concern for you.
On the plus side, this approach is much faster than processing the lines in a *loop*.

- `Get-Content -Raw` (PSv3+) reads the input file *as a whole*.
- Inline regex options `(?sm)` turn on both the **m**ulti-line and the **s**ingle-line option:

  - `m` means that `^` and `$` match the start and end of each *line* rather than the input string as a whole.
  - `s` means that metacharacter `.` matches `\n` characters too, so that an expression such as `.*` can be used to match *across lines*.
- `\r?\n` matches a single line break, both the CRLF and the LF variety.
- `(.*?)` is the capture group that (non-greedily) captures everything between the bounding lines.
- Note that the regex matches the *entire* input string, and then replaces it with just the substring (range) of interest, captured in the 1st (and only) capture group (`$1`).

Assuming that `$file` contains:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mapped Network Printers:
NetworkAddress\HP425DN    [DEFAULT PRINTER]
NetworkAddress\HP426DN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Local Printers:
```

the above yields:

```
NetworkAddress\HP425DN    [DEFAULT PRINTER]
NetworkAddress\HP426DN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Select-String` or `Where-Object` to look for words with a `\`. Taking that even further you could look for just the `server\printer` values with a RegEx like this:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\User1\Documents\Config.txt -Raw |
    Select-String '[A-Z0-9]+\\[A-Z0-9]+' -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Note that this makes the assumption the Server Names and Printers use only A-Z and 0-9, you may need to look for more characters if that is not a valid assumption.

Here would be an example of using `Where-Object` to filter for lines with `\`

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Config.txt' | Where-Object {$_ -like '*\*'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Doc= "C:\temp\test.txt"
$Doc_end ="C:\temp\testfiltered.txt"
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($Doc)

$cdata=""
while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) 
    {

        if ($line -like ('---*') )     {$Read = 0 }

        if ($Read -eq 1) {$cdata+= $line +  "`r`n"}

        if ($line -like ('Mapped Network Printers:*')) {$Read = 1}


    }


$cdata | Out-File $Doc_end -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are attempting with the `foreach-object` command and a few additional test conditions. Simply setting a flag when you encounter the `Mapped Network Printers:` line and then terminating output on the next line `-like "---*"` will work, e.g.

```
## positional parameters
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$infile
)
$beginprn = 0

get-content $infile | foreach-object {
    # terminate condition
    if ([int]$beginprn -eq 1 -and $_ -like "---*") {
        break
    }
    # output Mapped printers
    if ([int]$beginprn -eq 1) {
        write-host $_
    }
    # begin condition
    if ($_ -eq "Mapped Network Printers:") {
        $beginprn = 1
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mapped Network Printers:
NetworkAddress\HP425DN    [DEFAULT PRINTER]
NetworkAddress\HP4100N
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Local Printers:
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
PS> parseprn.ps1 .\tmp\prnfile.txt
NetworkAddress\HP425DN    [DEFAULT PRINTER]
NetworkAddress\HP4100N
```