# How to read lines between 2 special characters in txt-file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm almost a newbie to Powershell.
I need to read some specific lines in a text file and put them to different arrays.
I have a file looking like this:

```
[Servers]
Server1
Server2
Server3
Server4
[IP]
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.20
10.10.30.30
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.4
[Path]
C:\Log\*.log
D:\Files\*.txt
D:\Files\*.csv
D:\Files\*.xml
[Gateway]
10.10.10.1
10.10.30.2
192.168.1.1
```

My problem is that I need to read the lines in `[Servers]` (sometimes 3 lines and sometimes a lot more) and put these in to a array.
How do I select all lines between `[Servers]` and `[IP]` when I don't know the amount of lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Closely related: [Grabbing specific sections of a txt file via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44958963/45375)</sup>

If it's acceptable to read the entire file into memory first:

```
$regex = '(?ms)\A.*?^\[Servers\]\s*\r?\n(.*?)(?:\r?\n\[.*|(?:\r?\n)?\Z)'
$servers = (Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -replace $regex, '$1' -split '\r?\n'
```

Refactored into a simple **function** that accepts the input file and the name of the section of interest:

```
function get-SectionLines([string] $LiteralPath, [string] $SectionName) {
  $regex = '(?ms)\A.*?^\[{0}\]\s*\r?\n(.*?)(?:\r?\n\[.*|(?:\r?\n)?\Z)' -f [regex]::Escape($SectionName)
  (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $LiteralPath) -replace $regex, '$1' -split '\r?\n'
}

$servers = get-SectionLines file.txt Servers
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `Get-Content -Raw` reads the entire file into memory as a *single string*.
- `-replace` then operates on that one multi-line string, using a regex (regular expression) to match the *entire* input string, with a *capture group* (`(...)`) matching only the lines of interest, and replacing the entire string with just the capture group, effectively returning just the section's lines.
- Finally, `-split '\r?\n'` splits the extracted multi-line string into an array of lines.

**Explanation of the regex**:

- Inline regex options `(?sm)` turn on both the **m**ulti-line and the **s**ingle-line option:

  - `m` means that `^` and `$` match the start and end of each *line* rather than the input string as a whole.
  - `s` means that metacharacter `.` matches `\n` characters too, so that an expression such as `.*` can be used to match *across lines*.
- `\A` matches the very start of the (multi-line) input, and `\Z` the very end.
- `\r?\n` matches a single line break, both the CRLF and the LF variety.
- `(.*?)` is the capture group that (non-greedily) captures everything inside the section.
- `(?:\r?\n\[.*|(?:\r?\n)?\Z)` uses non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) to match everything *after* the section of interest, which can either be the start of the *next* section (a line break followed by a `[`) or *the end of the input file* (either with or without a trailing line break).
- Note that the regex matches the *entire* input string, and then replaces it with just the substring (range) of interest, captured in the 1st (and only) capture group (`$1`).

Answer (score 0):

Method classic :

```
$found=$false
$Listword=(gc C:\temp\list.txt).Split("[]".ToCharArray())

$Servers=foreach ($item in $Listword)
{
    if ($item -eq "IP") { break }

    if ($item -eq "Servers") {$found=$true; continue}

    if ($found) {$item}
}

$Servers
```